# Rails database model not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

I am creating a database model for an optimisation machine called the SimutronX. I have just change the variable name of one of the database keys and added an index.

Current migration file:

```
class CreateSimutronXes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :simutron_xes do |t|
      t.integer :num_constraints
      t.integer :num_coefficients
      t.boolean :max
      t.decimal :obj_func

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :simutron_xes, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Old migration file:

```
class CreateSimutronXes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :simutron_xes do |t|
      t.integer :num_constraints
      t.integer :num_coefficients
      t.boolean :min_max
      t.decimal :obj_func

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have saved the new file and run a `rails db:migrate` which has completed successfully. After I ran the migration I dropped into the rails console sandbox to test the model.

```
brotherlongtail:~/workspace/Simutronix (master) $ rails console --sandbox
Running via Spring preloader in process 8135
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 5.0.2)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
>> SimutronX.new
=> #<SimutronX id: nil, constraint: nil, coefficient: nil, min_max: nil, obj_func: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

The model doesn't seem to have updated. What are the additional steps required to get the model to properly update?

Comment: Did you change the original migration file or create another one?

Comment: Changed the original.

Comment: Then no changes are committed to the db unless you rollback all the migrations or at least to before that one

Comment: Easiest way is just to drop the table and create another migration file and the run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Done. All working now, thanks.

Comment: Great, I made an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the original migration after it has been run has no effect. You will either have to rollback with `rake db:rollback` to the version before that particular migration. I however find it easier when developing to just drop the table from the db and create a new migration and run that.

Rails keeps track of the migrations that have been run in the table `schema_migrations`, so one solution is also to remove the row corresponding the migration you want to change. That is not a very elegant solution however.